# The value of this.$store is undefined in the child component when using vue-custom-element with Vuex

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex, custom-element

I'm usiong Vue.js + typescript + vue-custom-element and

this is my main.ts file:

```js
import store from './store'
Vue.use(VueCustomElement)
Vue.customElement('skyroom-layout', new Layout({ store, i18n }).$options)
```

And this is my store:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import {storeUsers} from './modules/storeUsers'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: { storeUsers },
})
```

And finally this is my Layout.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <module-users></module-users>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**The problem:** I can access `this.$store` from layout component but it's undefined in users-module component as a child of Layout component

**Update:**
I found out that the Layout component is created twice!
I logged `this.$store` in the creator of Layout component and this is the log:

[image]

I reproduced the error in github:
https://github.com/rostamiani/vuejs-store-error

Comment: I solved the problem by importing `store` inside every component instead of using `this.$store`. But I'm still waiting for a better solution

Comment: Can you give more details as to why you are using `import Users from '@/components/users/Users.vue'` in your store.js file?

Comment: @jasonandmonte Thanks. That was just a mistake. I updated the question.

I reproduced the error in a github repo. check that